# Why does my bash script not work in my C program?

Tags: c, bash, sorting, fork, strcat

My program takes an arbitrary number of words from the user and stores them in a double pointer `**stringArr`. These values are then concatenated into a string which is then passed into a bash script I have.

The problem I have is that the bash script doesn't `echo` the command I want it to, and I am unsure why.

```
string = malloc(N * sizeof(char));

    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        strcat(string, stringArr[j]);
        strcat(string, " ");
    }

puts("\n\nYour input sorted in alphabetical order:");
    if (fork() == 0) {
        execl("./sortString.sh", "sortString.sh", string, NULL);
    }
```

```
#!/bin/bash
for NAME in "$@"
do
VAR=$VAR" "$NAME
done
echo $VAR | tr ’ ’ ’\n’ | sort | tr ’\n’ ’ ’
```

Is there something I am missing?

Note: the bash script is in the *same* directory as the program; the program works in regards to taking user input and it putting into the string `string`.

If you want to try out the bash script, an example of `string` I have passed through is: "one two three " (there is a space after 'three').

Comment: Your example is not minimal. Please figure out whether the problem is with the C or the bash by testing each one independently.

Comment: I have tried all sorts of tests, and I have no idea what else to try :/

Comment: You didn't show us the results of any of those tests.

Comment: It's 100% something to do with the either `execl()` or the bash script itself.

Comment: In the future, post a [mre] with questions like this. Also paste in code exactly. The last line in the shell script has close apostrophes instead of plain apostrophes, which happens when you type something with various autocorrect features enabled instead of pasting text. And `string = malloc(N * sizeof(char));` is wrong; that only allocates space for `N` characters, but the code shown copies `N` strings into it. That is either a bug in the original code or another artifact of typing in substitute code instead of pasting actual code.

Comment: The `strcat` function requires a pointer to a string as its first parameter. When you first call `strcat`, `string` does not actually point to a string -- it points to a buffer full of random garbage. You should also check if `execl` returns -- add some debug, logging, or error checking to your code so you can more easily understand what it *is* doing.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I am gonna try and apply what has been said. From the looks of it I need to start again and try to understand what I am doing a bit better.

Comment: While not perfect, your code is probably fixable. Do you know how to use the `gdb` or other C-lang debugger? That will help you a lot with the comments above AND just allows you to step thru one line at a time and confirm that each element is doing as needed. That is one funky shell script , fix what https://shellcheck.net flags. (won't solve your problem, but why work with questionable code). AND please add the current output form your project. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use the `exec()` family of functions to execute a shell script directly; they require the name of a proper executable. If you check the return value of your `execl()` call, I'm sure you'll see an error (`-1`), and `errno` will probably have been set to `ENOEXEC`.

You could try using `system()` instead, but it is generally frowned upon because you'd need to build a full (single) command string, and making sure that everything is properly escaped and such is error-prone.

Instead, I'd recommend that you give `"/bin/sh"` or `"/bin/bash"` as the first argument to `exec()`. Then, the args to `sh` would need to be the path of your script, and *then* the args that your script will use.

(this is what your shell does automatically when you run a script; it reads the `#!` line, and executes "/bin/bash your-script your-args...")

Your `string` allocation is too small. You're allocating space for N chars, but you're `strcat`ing N spaces into it, plus whatever is in your `stringArr` (which I assume is not full of empty strings).

Even then, you will have just one big string of args, but `exec()` wants them separated. Think of it like if you point quotes around all the args in bash; you get just one big argument, which contains spaces.

After you fix that (so that you have an array of strings rather than just one big one), you will run into problems with `execl()`. It takes the arguments separately, but you're trying to send one big array of them. You'll want `execv()` instead, which accepts an array of strings for the argument list. Remember that the first string in that list must be your script path.

Are you sure this wouldn't be easier to do with `qsort()`?

Comment: In at least some environments, you *can* execute a shell (or other) script directly with the exec-family functions, as long as it starts with an appropriate shebang line, as the OP's does.  See [the Linux `execve()` manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve).